# Fully loading ComponentData objects using GetList?

Tags: core-service, 2013-sp1

I need to access the 'Content' and 'Metadata' of a component and all of it's localized children. I need to do this using only one call if possible. I have the following code:

```
BluePrintChainFilterData bluePrintChainFilterData = new BluePrintChainFilterData() { Direction = BluePrintChainDirection.Down };
IdentifiableObjectData[] result = client.GetList(primaryBluePrintParentId, bluePrintChainFilterData);
foreach (ComponentData componentData in result)
{
    componentData.Content //not loaded and is null
    componentData.Metadata //not loaded and is null
}
```

Is there a way to fully/bulk load the data? Setting the filter's BaseColumns to ListBaseColumns.Extended gives additional data but excluding the 'Content' and 'Metadata'.

There is a similar question here: [How can I read the full Component data?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9719/how-can-i-read-the-full-component-data/9720) ,but I'm not sure if i understand Nuno Linhares' answer. It's possible I misinterpreted it, and in that case, sorry Nuno. Isn't .GetItems available in TOM.Net only?

> SDL Tridion doesn't provide a method to bulk-load components. When loading items from an OrganizationalItem (like a folder) you can use .GetItems which will load all the objects, but under the hood it's still hitting the database for each individual items anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CM Kernel (Core Service and TOM.NET) currently don't have a facility to bulk load items in a list.

As Nuno mentioned, TOM.NET has list methods that return (partially loaded) TOM.NET objects and TOM.NET objects have lazy loading behavior: as soon as you access a property which is not loaded yet, it will implicitly cause a full load on the item.

So, even on the TOM.NET, you may implicitly cause separate loads for each item, it's just not noticeable in your client code.
For a Core Service client, it will be painfully visible in your code. :-)